# Python permutations of heterogenous list elements

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

This is the sequence:

```
l = [['A', 'G'], 'A', ['A', 'C']]
```

I need the three element sequence back for each permutation

```
all = ['AAA','GAA','AAC','GAC']
```

I can't figure this one out! I'm having trouble retaining the permutation order!

Answer (score 6):

You want the [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

l = [['A', 'G'], 'A', ['A', 'C']]

print(["".join(p) for p in product(*l)])
```

Comment: brilliant solution +1 for product

Comment: Of course this only works because all of his values are 1-character strings… but then if that weren't true, his data format would be a horrible mess in the first place.